# When a genuinely concerned friend asks about another friend who is struggling, how can I reply in a meaningful way without it being backbiting?

Tags: backbiting

Sometimes, when I meet a friend (friend X, say) they will ask me about how another friend (friend Y) is going, with genuine concern about their well being.  Friend Y might not be doing well, but I'm uncomfortable explaining this to friend X as it might be interpreted as backbiting.

At the same time, saying to friend X that friend Y is fine seems inappropriate, as it could be considered lying (or is, at least, misleading), which might obstruct friend X helping friend Y.

Nor can I easily explain "it's inappropriate for me to talk about friend Y negatively", as it implies that friend Y is struggling, which may again be interpreted as backbiting.

**Question**: When a genuinely concerned friend asks about another friend who is struggling, how can I reply in a meaningful way without it being backbiting?

This dilemma doesn't seem to be addressed here yet.  The two most relevant backbiting questions I found were:

- [What is backbiting and what kinds of speech are considered backbiting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2511/17163) identifies what backbiting is: *Backbiting is talking about your (Muslim) brother in a manner which he dislikes.*
- [When is talking behind someone's back allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/484/17163) establishes some exceptions to backbiting

Comment: struggling mean ?

Comment: E.g. struggling with money, not being happy in their job or relationships.  Anything really.

Comment: If you would say the same thing in the presence of the friend as in his absence, it's a good indicator that's not backbiting.

Comment: Sister it'll be hard to provide an exact answer for this question. But IMHO, if my friend X ask me about my friend Y who is going through this sort of circumstances, then simply I'll explain all the situation he is going through but I'll also add good things about my friend Y as well.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones In order to answer unanswered questions; Could you try specifying a situation (I.e bad relationship, lost work, lost a relative or such) that the one answering could base his/her answer? Which also would make it less broad

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I’ve perceived of your interesting query, I presume that in case it would be permissible (not backbiting) that it is related to: Helping in eliminating/preventing sin, and turning the sinner to goodness; in this case it is permissible to mention about badness, and backbiting is permissible only in right/correct intention, otherwise it won’t be permissible.

But, based on my perception/assumption in (diverse) parts of backbiting:

E.g., if your speech to your X (present friend) is necessary/profitable to eliminate your Y’s sin (or may be removing him/her from hard dangerous situation…), then it would be permissible; **but on the other side, solely having conversion about (negative things/situation of) someone’s status which it is not a necessary/helpful conversion in its removing …, hence it doesn’t seem to be permissible, why? Since, as a rule of thumb, he/she (the absent person) won’t be satisfied that others have a dialogue about him/her in negative …**

---

Source:

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa14055)
- [www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Book/View/45286/27270/%D9%81%D8%B5%D9%84-17-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF%DB%8C-%DA%A9%D9%87-%D8%BA%DB%8C%D8%A8%D8%AA-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A2%D9%86%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%AC%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B2-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA)