# Regards a question about back biting/Gossiping

Tags: sin, backbiting

Is it considered backbiting if you tell your friend you want a divorce from your husband/wife? But you already told your husband/wife that you wanted one.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model i.e. what is on- and what is off-topic here I suggest you to take the [Tour] and check our [help].

Answer (score 2):

This is best answered by what quoting the Islamic definition of backbiting, you can use this as a criteria for assessing whether something is considered as back biting or not:

> It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) that
> the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him)
> said: “Do you know what gheebah (backbiting) is?” They said, “Allah
> and His Messenger know best.” He said, “Saying something about your
> brother that he dislikes.” It was said, “What if what I say about my
> brother is true?” He said, “If what you say is true then you have
> backbitten about him, and if it is not true, then you have slandered
> him.”
>
> The Messenger of Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said, "Do you
> know what is ghibah (backbiting)?" The Companions said: "Allah and His
> Messenger know better." Thereupon he said, "Ghibah is talking about
> your (Muslim) brother in a manner which he dislikes." It was said to
> him: "What if my (Muslim) brother is as I say." He said, "If he is
> actually as you say, then that is ghibah; but if that is not in him,
> that is slandering."

Those two questions contain more details on backbiting:

- [When is talking behind someone's back allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/484/when-is-talking-behind-someones-back-allowed?rq=1)
- [What is backbiting and what kinds of speech are considered backbiting?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-backbiting-and-what-kinds-of-speech-are-considered-backbiting?rq=1)

Comment: :) Never saw these two linked questions before on ISE even if I answered a few similar ones.