# Backbiting is permitted?

Tags: allah, sin, backbiting

if backbiting is telling stuff behind the back that you cant speak on their face , what if you can speak whatever you want on their face because you are brave and bold. so does the sin of backbiting really apply on you ?

Comment: Telling behind to who? Indirectly to the original person whom you can't speak directly or to any one else ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is talking behind someone's back allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/484/when-is-talking-behind-someones-back-allowed)

Comment: what i meant with that was , talking behind someones back the same thing you are not afraid of speaking on there face @An_Elephant